# Perform multi-language search sitecore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, sitecore

I have small issue with search results where its showing duplicate items because it has different version created and sometimes it only shows default language version.

The code i have is as per below,

Below method returns IQueryable<>

```
return context.GetQueryable<SearchResult>().Where(item => item["Enable"] = "1");
```

After I get the results I can see different version of each item, later on i do filtering/sorting as per below,

```cs
results.AddRange(query.Where(item => item.Title.Equals("keywordinput"))
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.SortOrder)
    .ThenBy(item => item.DateTime));
```

Soon as i use the linq, it's only showing default language not based on context language. I've tried applying language when running `GetQueryable<>` but then I only get item that has language but I would also like to display other items  that don't have language i.e. the default language.

Is there a way I can do this?  for example suppose i have

Item1 has two version en and us

Item2 has only one version en

So if someone search "item" then im expecting two results to be displayed

Item1 - us version

Item2 - en version

Comment: What do you mean by `but i would also like to display other items i.e. the default.`?

Comment: for example Item1 has two version en and us

Comment: Maybe it's lack of coffee but it's still not clear to me what you want to achieve. Can you add some example to your question?

Comment: Do you mean a language fall back? i.e. This item doesn't have a us version use the en eversion even though my language is us?

Comment: Sorry accidentally pressed add comment but couldn't  edit till 5min! Anyhow..what i mean something like this for example 
Item1 has two version en and us 
Item2 has only one version en 

so if someone search item then i want two results 
Item1 - us version 
Item2 - en version

Comment: @Liam yes thats correct